# Ubuntu One file sync pause/resume for large files

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

Dropbox client has a "pause syncing" option. Is there a way to pause/resume large files sync in Ubuntu One?

I want to make some video calls and the transfer consumes valuable bandwidth, making call quality poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no specific pause/resume in ubuntu one. Starting with 11.04, it will start uploading where it left off after a disconnect. Large files should continue where they left off. You can disconnect the client from the command line, or by using the Ubuntu One Control Panel.

This can be seen by the output of u1sdtool --current-transfers and disconnecting and reconnecting... Here's an example with an ISO:

```
john@Monolith:~/.cache/ubuntuone/log$ u1sdtool --current-transfers
Current uploads:
  path: /home/john/Ubuntu One/precise-dvd-amd64.iso
    deflated size: 1611418705
    bytes written: 9506000
Current downloads: 0
john@Monolith:~/.cache/ubuntuone/log$ u1sdtool --current-transfers
Current uploads:
  path: /home/john/Ubuntu One/precise-dvd-amd64.iso
    deflated size: 1611418705
    bytes written: 17598000
Current downloads: 0
john@Monolith:~/.cache/ubuntuone/log$ u1sdtool -d
john@Monolith:~/.cache/ubuntuone/log$ u1sdtool --current-transfers
Current uploads: 0
Current downloads: 0

john@Monolith:~/.cache/ubuntuone/log$ u1sdtool -c

.... After a minute or two...

john@Monolith:~/.cache/ubuntuone/log$ u1sdtool --current-transfers
Current uploads:
  path: /home/john/Ubuntu One/precise-dvd-amd64.iso
    deflated size: 1611418705
    bytes written: 39760920
Current downloads: 0
```

Comment: Great! Seems like this `u1sdtool` is what I needed. But from the commands you have shown, `u1sdtool --quit` would restart **automatically** the daemon after a few minutes... is that right?

Comment: No, I messed up my paste, it will not restart. I have corrected my paste. I should have used -d (disconnect) not -q.

If this answered your question. Could you mark it as such?

Comment: Yeah that is what I needed. But I still can't get why `--quit` would restart the daemon automatically. Thanks

Comment: @Alexandre it did not start it automatically. I messed up the paste.